# Utilizing Decrement in Sequelize does no check min validation

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to decrement the `quantity` column for each Soda item

`Soda.js`

```js
const Soda = db.define('Soda', {
    id: {
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    label: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    },
    quantity: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      validate: {
        min: {
          args: [0],
          msg: 'Quantity must be greater than 0',
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

The main issue is that I am using the `decrement` function which is not checking the value of the instance when decrementing the value in the database.

This means that if I decrement below the value of `0`, my validation will not reject this since it is not being checked.

`api.js`

```js
  const decrementResult = await db.models.Soda.decrement('quantity', { where: { id: req.body.id } }); // can result in negative values
```

I found the topic being spoken about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643436/sequelize-validation-with-increment-function) but am unsure how to reload the instance or manually use a transaction.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?